# php Login page access issue (wikihow)

Tags: php, authentication, registration

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the php login page code specified here:http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL . I registered a user, then enter the same credentials in the login page and I'm redirected to protected_page.php with the following output

"You are not authorized to access this page. Please login."

Comment: what do you want?? r u creating login page

Comment: Yes, trying to create a login page.  Unable to login with emailid, password. I verified that the email id is present in the mysql db

Comment: so you want us to debug someone else's code/tutorial, and not your specific code?

Comment: Yes please. I'm learning php and cant figure out what the issue is

Comment: We need your code, not this tutorial..

Comment: How do you know there is something wrong with the php code on that tutorial? It is probably an issue with your code, and that you did not copy something correctly, or use your correct credentials. We need to see **your** code, not the tutorial.

Comment: I've been searching around since a while and many have had the same issue. Looks like it's a config issue with xampp. Could someone please explain what this means?

"My issue was in my php.ini file. I had to change

session.save_path = "/var/php_sessions"

to:session.save_path = "THE_DOCUMENT_ROOT_FOLDER_FROM_MY_HOST"."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this using the following in cmd

```
attrib -r -a C:\xampp\tmp /S /D
```

For linux:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 \xampp\tmp //or should it be 775
```